# Installing Linux Cinnamon in Virutal machine on Lenovo Ideapad

Tags: linux, cinnamon

I have Lenovo Ideapad i3 7th gen 4GB ram laptop. So I want to install Linux cinnamon in a virtual machine. So if i allocate 2gb ram for Linux. Does my windows os performance will be affected. I will be working with Visual studio in windows. So if i allocate 2gb of ram to Linux. Will the Windows OS will be working well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your performance will be affected, but it also depends on the Windows memory usage and if you have fast harddisk/SSD or not. Even with the full 4GB for Windows only and development with an IDE it's not very much memory. I would suggest an update to 8GB/12GB/16GB depending on the amount of used memory slots/possible upgrade options and available budget. You can of course test how good or bad Windows and the virtual machine perform and tweak the memory settings accordingly.

Comment: Yeah sure @Freedy thanks for info will try.